# SSIS Expression issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, foreach-loop-container

I have a folder where I have created a number of files with a date embedded (the date comes from the input file, e.g. 297-20180128.exp). I have `Data20180128.txt` and `Footer20180128.txt` along with a lot of other files in my folder.

I want to move all of the files containing the date (`20180128`) into an Archive folder. I have set up a `FOREACH LOOP CONTAINER` using `FOR EACH FILE ENUMERATOR`. In my container I have a `File System Task` to move the file.

My problem is getting the loop to find the files I want. I have the date (from the input file in a variable called Date. In both the Files: box of the Collection and in the FileFilter property of the container I tried both `"*"+ @[User::Date]+"*.*"` and `"*"+ @[User::Date]+"*"`. The first one evaluates to `*20180128*.*` and the second one to `*20180128*` It doesn't like the first one because of the period (?) and the second one doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Typo - first expression should be "*"+ @[User::Date]+"*.*" which evaluates to *20180128*.* (which works in Windows Explorer)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with `"*"+ @[User::Date]+"*.*"` (although, personally i'd just use `"*" + @[User::Date] + ".*"`, as the date is adjacent to the extension). I **assume** that your variable `@[User::Date]` is using the WSTR datatype, and not date or integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS File Filter in For Each File Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067171/ssis-file-filter-in-for-each-file-enumerator)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `FileSpec` property in the expression to write the expression you need

```
"*"+ @[User::Date]+"*.*"
```

[image]

**References**

- [SSIS: Dynamically specify folder path for Foreach File Enumerator in Foreach Loop Container](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/changliw/2010/07/19/ssis-dynamically-specify-folder-path-for-foreach-file-enumerator-in-foreach-loop-container/)
- [Foreach File Enumerator](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803195/Foreach-File-Enumerator-in-SSIS)

Comment: Now The FileSystem Tasks Bombs - the value of FileToBeMoved is E:\Anthem_ESI_Trigger_File\297-20180128.exp (where the file is) but the File System task says "Error: 0xC002F304 at Move date stamped files to Archive, File System Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "The given path's format is not supported.".

Comment: @DickRosenberg In the fore each loop what is the file name retrieval property you chose? In the file system task what is the expression?

Comment: No Expression. The Destination is a variable called Archive which has the expression "E:\\Anthem _ESI_Trigger_File\\Archive\\"" and the source is a variable called FilesToBeMoved which is populated by the Loop. I put a script task in to display the value of FilesToBeMoved and it says E:\Anthem_ESI_Trigger_File\297-2018128.exp (which is correct)

Comment: Just change `"E:\\Anthem _ESI_Trigger_File\\Archive\\"` to `E:\Anthem _ESI_Trigger_File\Archive\` because \\ is used only in expressions

Comment: @DickRosenberg is the issue solved? if no why not giving a reply? if yes why not accepting the answer? Instead of saying `That solves that problem. Thanks` you should accept it

Comment: When you put something in a variable you ARE using the Expression Editor

Comment: @DickRosenberg No this is not true, you can assign an expression to the variable, or just assign a fixed **value**